# "das" vs "dies"

Tags: demonstrative-pronoun

From what I have seen on grammar specialized websites **das** and **dies** are not declined when they are used as subjects in combination with **sein**. Example: **Dies sind Zeitungen.**

Apart from this, are there any other instances where das/dies can't be declined?

For example when the object of the action is a masculine noun and we wish to replace it with das/dies:

> Ich habe einen **Hammer** gefunden.

With das/dies:

> =》Ich habe das/dies in der Garage gefunden.

or

> =》Ich habe **den/diesen** in der Garage gefunden.

Are **diesen/den** in accordance with the grammar rules here? Do you think **das/dies** would fit better?

Edit: I would much apreciate some other examples of sentences 
in which  the pronouns **das** and **dies** are not declined and don't act as subjects, if there are any.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Exodus 1:1 of the Lutherbibel, why Dies instead of Diese?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39324/in-exodus-11-of-the-lutherbibel-why-dies-instead-of-diese)

Comment: This is a duplicate, even though this is obscured by unclear wording. What the author apparently intends to ask for is the lack of _[agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agreement_(linguistics))_ of words like «dies» and «das». This can be seen in the comments to my answer where I have explained that there is nothing unusual about these words with regard to _declension._

Comment: @mach It is unusual that *-es* is optional, is it not? *Er hat dies(es) vergessen*, but only *er hat jenes, sein(e)s vergessen*.

Comment: Relevant: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5783/dies-oder-dieses https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44627/difference-between-dieses-und-dies-in-accusative https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44852/dies-before-a-noun https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54883/in-welchem-kontext-wird-das-wort-dies-benutzt

Comment: @mach No. I want to hear a native's opinion on this.

Comment: @David Vogt   These  are very good explanations. Although some are written in german,  I manage to understand the logic behind them. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidVogt: The reason why I have not mentioned «dieses» is that it would be very unusual in the deictic use, which was the only one this question in its original form referred to. Now that it has been heavily reworded, an answer needs to explain the difference between anaphoric and deictic use – which has already been done in: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54883/in-welchem-kontext-wird-das-wort-dies-benutzt (Unfortunately, I cannot change my close vote after the question has been reworded.)

Comment: @Rare: Of course I am a native German speaker – why else would I have thought that the translation of «Kongruenz» into English would be “congruence” when it is really “agreement”?

Comment: Sorry for  assuming that. I thought my question was clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words *das* or *dies* are declined regularly. There are no rules that restrict their declension.

The subject of a sentence is almost always in the nominative case (exceptions are extremely rare). So when the words *das/dies* function as the subject of a sentence, they will take their nominative declension form. When they are used in other grammatical functions that have other cases, they will take other declension forms in the appropriate case.

---

Being neutrum pronouns, the accusative form of *dies/das* is the same as the nominative form:

- Nominative/accusative: *dies/das*
- Genitive: *dieses* (rare)/*dessen*
- Dative: *diesem/dem*

Examples with dative:

> Ich kann **diesem/dem** nicht zustimmen.
>
> Von **diesem/dem** halte ich gar nichts.

Examples with genitive (note that a pronominal use of the genitive *dieses* would be extremely unlikely and confusing because it sounds the same as nominative *dieses):*

> **Dessen** Einfluss nimmt zu.
>
> Ich entsinne mich **dessen.**

---

What happens with the case you have given as an example is that it does not use neutrum *das* or *dies* at all, but masculine *der* or *dieser* instead:

> Ich habe **diesen/den** in der Garage gefunden.

This can be shown by transforming the sentence into the passive voice:

> **Dieser/der** ist in der Garage gefunden worden.

With neutrum *dies/das,* the sentence would be as follows:

> Ich habe **dies/das** in der Garage gefunden.

Comment: Intense. But wasn't the question about rules that restrict declension, if they exist ?

Comment: @a_donda: As I had said in the first sentence, they are declined regularly. But I will take your advice and try to make this more obvious still.

Comment: Ok(+1), that would mean that the question is based on a wrong assumption ? It felt like it wouldn't answer that ... but I may as well be wrong.

Comment: @a_donda What do you mean by "It felt like it wouldn't answer that"??

Comment: It does not answer "are there any rules that restrict the declension of pronouns"

Comment: Right, you mean "I had the impression that..". Sorry for asking, but I have got big problems with literal tranlations that don't make any sense...

Comment: "So when the words das/dies function as the subject of a sentence, they will take their nominative declension form. "                                                                                 
                                                                                                          Except these pronouns can't be declined at all when they function as subjects. Take for example the sentence **These are newspapers**. If we were to replace the subject with a demonstrative  we would say **Das/Dies sind Zeitungen.**

Comment: @Rare: Now I see what you mean. The question you really wanted to ask is why there is no congruence in number between _dies/das_ and the predicative expression (the word _es_ behaves the same, BTW). I’d invite you to reformulate your question, but it is a duplicate and has been answered several times already.

Comment: @mach You are assumption is incorrect. I wanted to know if there are other cases where das/dies doesn't decline by gender, number and case. I guess I could have worded it differently. But

Answer (score -1):

This question cannot be answered without an available context. If you went into your garage and found something surprising such as a pistol, for example, you would show the item to someone and say "ich habe das in der Garage gefunden!". In contrast, if someone asked you to look for a pistol in your garage, you would show the item and say "ich habe diese (feminine) gefunden" because the feminine word "Pistole" constitutes common background for speaker and hearer.

Comment: What is wrong about this answer? The donvoter is kindly asked to give a reason! Thanks!

Comment: Beim nächsten Mal könntest Du einen Revolver finden. Oder einen Colt.

Answer (score -2):

im a native german and here is my answer:
Actually, most germans dont know the difference themselves, so the answer really is that you (when talking normally) almost never say "dies", but im not shure however, how much of a formal german you learn

Comment: Welcome to German SE. Unfortunately I'm not convinced, that an answer is helpful, which I would paraphrase as: *Since few people know the difference, it does not matter.* I suggest to either improve the answer by enriching it with some hard facts or delete it by yourself.